# How to close the pygame window without using quit()/sys.exit() so that I don't quit the loop outside of the game?

Tags: python, pygame, chat

I am creating a chat system and want to insert a game made with Pygame. In the state_machine file of the chat system, I set a state of the client as `S_GAMING`. When the client type "game" in the `S_LOGGEDIN` state, the state will be changed into `S_GAMING` and when the game is over, the user can quit the game either by clicking the "x" button or by waiting for 3 seconds.

I have some trouble closing the game window without exiting the chat system.

when I used `pygame.quit()`, the window will froze.
When I tried `pygame.quit()` and `sys.exit()` or `quit()`, I exited the chat system as well.

**This is a part of the game.py file:**

```
run = True

gameOver = False

timer = 0

while run:

   clock.tick(27)   

   #check events
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           run = False

   if not gameOver:

       drawWindow()
       for each in barriers:
           if each.isHit:
               gameOver = True
   else:
       if timer < 81:
           win.blit(game_over,(0,0))
           timer +=1 
           pygame.display.update() 
       else:
           run = False

pygame.display.quit()

pygame.quit()
```

**This is a part of the chat_state_machine file:**

```
elif self.state == S_GAMING:

    import game

    self.state = S_LOGGEDIN
```

I know this is a specific question and I can provide more code if the above is not clear.
Hopefully, I can get an answer. I am all ears.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution: Once you exit pygame the code should throw an exception, in that case you can switch run to False and start a new loop

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True

while run:
   try:
      screen.fill((0,0,0))

      for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              pygame.quit()

      clock.tick(120)
      pygame.display.update()
   except:
      run = False

while not run:
  #Your other code here
  pass
```